# MapPageRoute fails to redirect to specified aspx page

Tags: asp.net, maproute

I have the following in my RouteConfig.cs file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            // route default URL to index.aspx
            routes.MapPageRoute(
                routeName: "LoginPageRoute",
                routeUrl: "login",
                physicalFile: "~/Login.aspx"
            );

            routes.MapPageRoute("LoginPageRoute2", "login2", "~/Login.aspx");


        }
```

However if I try to access my WebApp using "login" or "login2" I get a resource cannot be found error message.

- http://localhost:4200/login2 - fails
- http://localhost:4200/login - fails
- http://localhost:4200/Login.aspx - loads fine

My Global.asax has the following

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Comment: Did you verify your methods get hit? Set a breakpoint or add logging?

Comment: @mason Yes, I ran my project in debug via Visual Studio and verified that Application_Start() and RegisterRoutes() were called.

I'm a bit new to aspx and route mapping so I'm not sure how to debug the flow for trying to access "/login". Webpage just directly goes to a 404 error and doesn't hit any of my debug points.

Comment: Have you tried rearranging the order you map your page routes in? Perhaps mapping them before you map the default MVC route?

Comment: @mason :D So I had just found another post that showed how to trace the route table lookup and I noticed that I was not getting the correct route. Then I saw your comment so I moved my routes to the top....and....magic. It's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A comment from somebody under my question guided me to the solution which was to move my custom routes ahead of the default routes.

Adding the following to Global.asax helped prove that this was indeed the issue.

```
        public override void Init()
        {
            base.Init();
            this.AcquireRequestState += showRouteValues;
        }

        protected void showRouteValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context == null)
                return;
            var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }
```

Putting a breakpoint on

```
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
```

Showed that my "login" mapping was using the default route mapping instead of my custom route mapping.

Thanks again @mason!